# When I use function pointer to define the set order, but the answer is Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

When I use function pointer to define the set order, but the answer is Segmentation fault

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool cmp(int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::set<int, decltype(cmp)*> mse;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++ i)
        mse.insert(i);
    for (auto ite = mse.begin(); ite != mse.end(); ++ ite)
        std::cout << *ite << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The answer is `Segmentation fault`. I am a beginner to learn C++, thanks for your answer.

Comment: You didn't actually tell your set what comparison function to use, just what type.

Comment: E.g `std::set<int, decltype(cmp)*> mse(cmp);` . And fyi, consider using either a lambda or a functor. They generally inline much better in such usage circumstances. [Example here](https://godbolt.org/z/4addhT6n8).

Answer (score 2):

```
decltype(cmp)*
```

The type of `cmp` is `bool (int, int)`. Therefore, the above type declaration is: `bool (*)(int, int)`.

Therefore, your set declaration is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
std::set<int, bool (*)(int, int)> mse;
```

Now, take a look at this declaration. Which part of this declaration results in `std::set` using `cmp` as the comparator? This is a trick question because, of course, the answer is "none of it".

You must use an overloaded `std::set` constructor that takes an instance of the comparator as the comparison function:

```
std::set<int, decltype(cmp)*> mse{cmp};
```

Comment: Thanks. I know, I should tell the ```set``` to use the comparator